# How to use special character (#) in select query in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Let's say I have a table with 2 columns (id, name) - How can I create a select query, use the name of the second field as name#user (I need to import this to 3rd party) - so my results will looks like:

```
id,name#user
1,Dan
2,Sarah
```

Answer (score 1):

To specify a named parameter, use the @ character followed by an identifier, such as @param_name. For example, this query finds all the words in a specific Shakespeare corpus with counts that are at least the specified value.

```html
#standardSQL
SELECT
  word,
  word_count
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
WHERE
  corpus = @corpus
  AND word_count >= @min_word_count
ORDER BY
  word_count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Including special characters in the names of your columns is unfortunately not supported by BigQuery at the moment.

See [this paragraph](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names) of the documentation:

> A column name must contain only letters (a-z, A-Z), numbers (0-9), or underscores (_), and it must start with a letter or underscore. The maximum column name length is 300 characters.

You will need to add a renaming step before export to your third party client.